# How to keep unmatched rows as nulls + rightly matched rows - bigquery sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following tables (user_id is different than shown output for obvious reasons):

```
Table A
user_id | acc_activation_date | generated_Date
1       | 13-04-2018          | 13-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 14-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 15-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 16-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 17-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 18-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 19-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 20-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 21-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 22-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 23-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 24-04-2018 
1       | 13-04-2018          | 25-04-2018 

Table B
user_id | acc_activation_date | joined_date | engagement_l1
1       | 13-04-2018          | 13-04-2018  | 1
1       | 13-04-2018          | 22-04-2018  | 1
1       | 13-04-2018          | 25-04-2018  | 0
```

The expected output:

```
user_id | generated_date | acc_activation_date | joined_date | engagement_l1
1       | 13-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          | 13-04-2018  | 1 
1       | 14-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          |             |  
1       | 15-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          |             |  
1       | 16-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          |             |  
1       | 17-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          |             |  
1       | 18-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          |             | 
1       | 19-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          |             |  
1       | 20-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          |             |
1       | 21-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          |             | 
1       | 22-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          | 22-04-2018  | 1 
1       | 23-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          |             | 
1       | 24-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          |             |
1       | 25-04-2018     | 13-04-2018          | 25-04-2018  | 0
```

I've tried possibly every combination of left join, right join, full join I can think of and it's not working in bigquery SQL. It's my first time using bigquery sql so it might be different to other IDEs.

This is my latest query:

```
  select distinct a.generated_Date,
  a.user_id, 
  a.acc_activation_date,
  b.engagement_l1,
  b.joined_date
  from TableB b
  full join TableA a
on a.user_id=b.user_id 
order by generated_date
```

This gives me duplicated rows: [image]

If I also add a join on dates:

```
  select distinct a.generated_Date,
  a.user_id, 
  a.acc_activation_date,
  b.engagement_l1,
  b.joined_Date
  from TableB b
  full join TableA a 
on a.user_id=g.user_id and b.generated_date=a.joined_date
order by generated_date
```

and the results dont give me the extra rows I need [image]

Comment: Full join should get you there, post your query.

Comment: @Andrew done, added how the output looks too

Comment: Please read : [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What do you mean by extra rows?  Your second query returns 13 rows, which is what you have in your desired result.  Here's a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2hr8czShXr4DcZnng8K62Y/0) - it's not BigQuery, but that's not relevant. Joins are joins.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a left join to get the final column.

The activation date can be derived from a window function.

```
SELECT
  a.user_id,
  a.generated_date,
  MAX(b.activation_date)
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY a.user_id
    )
      AS activation_date,
  b.transaction_date
FROM
  TableA   a
LEFT JOIN
  TableB   b
    ON  a.user_id        = b.user_id
    AND a.generated_date = b.transaction_date
ORDER BY
  a.user_id,
  a.generated_date
```

As a general tip, if you have DISTINCT in your query to "fix" the results, there's probably a mistake. (It's a code smell.)

Also, please make sure your sample data and query use the same table and column names?

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, but that's not solving the issue - I just fixed the original post so hopefully now it's clearer, sorry about that

Comment: @amestrian What results do you get with that query? Have you changed the column names correctly? It works here; https://dbfiddle.uk/VmOS2xqR

Answer (score 0):

A simple left join should do it. The full join is the part that is causing duplicates.

```
select a.user_id,
       a.generated_date,
       a.acc_activation_date,
       b.joined_date,
       b.engagement_l1
from table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
  ON a.user_id = b.user_id
     AND a.generated_date = b.joined_date
```